# Why date of any "Hindu festival" changes every year?

Tags: tradition, festivals

'Christmas' occurs on 25th December every year.

But why the dates of Hindu festivals vary from year to year?

Are there any references of this in Hinduism?

Comment: I am new here, and not intended to duplicate other's text.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange. Possible duplicate doesn't mean you have duplicated other's text. It means the question you have asked is already present on the site and answered. We link that question to avoid repetition. To avoid duplicates, you can search for already asked question in the top bar and also check the suggestions shown to you while writing up the question.